# How to remove motion blur from images using the compositor?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, blur

I'd like to know if it's possible to use the compositor for removing motion blur from image sequences, originally from a video footage. Using filter -> sharpen is OK, but I'm trying to find some better node setups. Any ideas?

Comment: Motion blur isn't something that can be removed with Blender. One other thing to keep in mind is the higher the framerate your camera is recording, the less motion blur the video will have. However, there is research in trying to remove motion blur. This link may be of interest: http://www.cse.cuhk.edu.hk/leojia/projects/motion_deblurring/

Comment: What you are looking for is generally called deconvolution kernel. It is a rather math-intensive operation, and isn't something that Blender can do out-of-the-box.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's about a feature not currently found in Blender. You could try asking for application suggestions over at the [Audio-Video Production Stack Exchange](http://avp.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Motion blur is reducing the information in the image. There is no way to add that information back. Say that you took a video of something blurry, that looks like motion blur but isn't. There is no way (for a mathematical operation) to know if that objects should be deblurred.

There are approximations, but they are quite complex math operations and they always leave artifacts (due to missing information).